# How to obtain transaction logs via RPC?

Tags: rust, rpc, solana-client

My off-chain program is sending transactions to Solana, and I want to inspect the logs of the transaction inside this program.

```
// Send transaction
let transaction_signature = client.send_transaction(&my_transaction)?;
// Get logs
let my_logs = client.i_want_this_get_logs_method(&transaction_signature)?;
// Futher log-related logic...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/4726/285) answer helped me to find `get_transaction()` method of `solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient`, so to obtain logs of the transaction one needs to do the following:

```
let signature = rpc_client.send_and_confirm_transaction(&tx)?;
let transaction_with_meta = rpc_client.get_transaction(
    &signature,
    UiTransactionEncoding::Json,
)?;
// transaction itself can be extracted this way:
let transaction = transaction_with_meta.transaction;
```

This struct contains 3 fields: `meta`, `transaction` and `version`.

- `transaction` is what was actually sent to the network (reсent blockhash, instructions, accounts, signatures and so on)
- `meta` contains different meta-information (see [this](https://docs.rs/solana-transaction-status/1.14.10/solana_transaction_status/struct.UiTransactionStatusMeta.html)), logs are among it.

```
// Type annotation here is just for verbosity 
let logs:Vec<String> = transaction
    .meta
    .log_messages
    .expect("There are no logs!");
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the log messages for a transaction, you can use the `getTransaction` endpoint from JSON RPC, and then pull out the `meta.logMessages`.

Not all RPC endpoints provide log messages, however, so you may not receive them in the response. In that case, you'll need to find a different node / talk to your provider / use a different provider.

More information about `getTransaction` at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getTransaction

Comment: I was looking for Rust API, but your answer helped me to find the relevant method in `solana-client` docs. I'll post my findings in separate answer.